# Check for typeOf undefined not working?

Tags: javascript, scope, undefined, declaration, typeof

Can someone explain why this doesn't work?

```
setOrientation: function() {
    if (typeof oldOrientation !== 'undefined') console.log(oldOrientation);
    let oldOrientation = orientation;
    //other code
}
```

This throws `oldOrientation is undefined`.  I eventually simply removed `let` and it started working, but I'm having a hard time fully understanding why.  I assume it's something to do with scoping?

I have fixed the issue by declaring `oldOrientation` globally, I just want to understand why the comparison for `typeof` wasn't working the way it was.

Comment: because you define it inside of the function vs making it global.

Comment: But regardless, shouldn't it the comparison have returned `"undefined"`, thus throwing no error?

Comment: hoisting.......

Comment: [Learn you some hoisting](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Hoisting)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[From MDN `let`:](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let)

> In ECMAScript 2015, let bindings are not subject to Variable Hoisting,
>   which means that let declarations do not move to the top of the
>   current execution context. Referencing the variable in the block
>   before the initialization results in a ReferenceError (contrary to a
>   variable declared with var, which will just have the undefined value).
>   The variable is in a "temporal dead zone" from the start of the block
>   until the initialization is processed.

Means you used a variable before it is defined.

---

If you used to using `var`, what happens is the `var` declarations are moved to the top of the block scope because of hoisting. So the following function

```
function foo() {
  console.log(typeof bar)
  var bar = "123";
}
```

is seen as

```
function foo() {
  var bar;
  console.log(typeof bar)
  bar = "123";
}
```

But when you use `let`, their is no hoisting so the declaration is not moved to the top of the block.

Comment: Helps a little, but does this imply that Chrome is handling the error incorrectly?

Comment: I run it in chrome and get `"message": "Uncaught ReferenceError: oldOrientation is not defined",` so looks like it is correctly returning the error message.

Comment: @epascarello javascript noob here, i come from c# and having a hard time understanding what you're saying. So basically the issue is that `let` isn't using variable hoisting, therefore having that if statement wouldn't make sense if you're declaring your variables with `let` ? But with `var` that would be fine?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Hoisting And in the C# world you would not be able to compile a file that has a variable used before it is declared. That is what happens with `let`

Comment: @epascarello yes I would say that's a benefit of using a strongly typed language, you don't have to worry about this at all xD. But just to clarify, because the world is unfortunately moving into a javascript and not C#, using let is effectively like a defense mechanism for an issue like this?

Comment: And using a linting tool in your IDE and build you get the same errors you get with a compiled language.

Answer (score 2):

Imagine this simplified case:

```
let a = 1;

{
 alert(a);
 let a = 2;
}
```

Then the *alert(a)* will do a variable lookup. That starts at the current scope ( the block), which has its own variable declared (*let a*) but not set yet (*a = 2*) , therefore its undefined yet. The upper is equal to:

```
let a = 1;

{
 let a /* = undefined */;
 alert(a);
 a = 2;
}
```

(That variables are declared before the code gets executed is called [hoisting](https://de.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hoisting)...)

Comment: This is a good answer, you should mention hoisting though and possibly point to a resource for learning more about hoisting in JS

Comment: Sorry, but are you saying that due to hoisting, at the time of the comparison, the variable *was* declared, but when it tried to log it, it was undefined?

Comment: @rather notsay yes. When a variable is declared, its set to undefined.